# QR via Householder: less computationally complex variants?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, linear-solver

I'm a probabilist and need to do a few computations for a rather big linear least squares problem, so I'm trying to optimize the computation as far as is feasible to me.

In computing the QR factorization of the matrix representation $A$ of an overdetermined system $Ax=b$ using the Householder reflections, the commonly stated algorithms suggest that you compute the outer product $uu^\top$ for some $u \in U^\perp$ and a hyperplane $U$, following a geometric motivation.

This yields the Householder reflector $H = I - \frac{2}{\langle u, u\rangle } uu^\top$.

Now, in order to eliminate subcolumns of the columns of $A$, multiply $A$ from left with $H$.

1. The computation of $uu^\top$ requires $m^2$ multiplcations.
2. The direct computation of the product $HA$ requires $m^2n$ multiplications.

The product $AH$ is equivalent (or expands) to $A-\frac{2}{\langle u, u\rangle} u(u^\top A)$ which requires $2mn$ multiplications -- by associativity.

I might be missing something rather obvious. Still, is there a way to avoid this computation on every iteration and reduce the complexity from $2mn$ flops?

Comment: You shouldn't form $uu^\top$ directly, if that's what you mean, it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I should have made my point clearer. I'll edit the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You haven't said anything about how large your problem is, but you should be aware that there are parallel blocked algorithms for computing the QR factorization that are much faster in practice than a straight forward implementation of the Householder transformation.  You probably don't want to implement this yourself.  Rather, you should be using an efficient library routine.

Comment: First, at the risk of stating the obvious, you shouldn't write your own code for this but rather make use of one of a the many well-tested libraries available. Second, you need to touch every matrix element of $A$ at least once to compute $u^TA$ -- no matter how, -- so $mn$ is a hard lower bound. Hence there's not much to gain. Also, in most metrics, researcher-hours (spent implementing or tuning) are much more expensive than CPU-hours.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I completely agree that it is in general preferable to use well-tested and efficient libraries, also with regard to costs incurred. I, however, in this particular case, would like to actually try to understand "what's going on inside the black box." There are statistical subtleties to the data which I would like to attempt to consider. For now, I am at first looking for pointers and ideas. My motivation is to learn some graduate-level numerical analysis for statistical computations in the scarce spare time. I think LLS is a perfect candidate to start with.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, I'll take a look at the blocked algorithms.

Comment: @Christian: I see, I've been pondering over a less concrete idea to postpone the computation of $u\top A$. Might have been nonsense. I'll run through Golub and van Loan and see if I can formulate the idea somewhat more concretely.

Comment: If your problem size is big enough for you to worry about speed, maybe you could try an iterative solver to solve the least square problem.

Comment: 1. You probably mean the product $HA$ instead of $AH$? 2. I don't find the structure of the question very clear. You compare a method that requires $O(m^2n)$ per step and one that requires $O(mn)$ per step, and then you ask how to beat the $O(mn)$ method? Is that correct?